# I am trying to verify that Rows(2 - 25) are less than or equal to Row1 using Selenium C#. I don't know how to proceed from there

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow

here is a snippet of the code: I need to know how to verify that the fist row is larger than the next 25 rows

```
    <tbody>

      <tr class="row-1">
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td data-r="" class="cell1 " align="right">
            30000
        </td>
        <td data-r="" class="cell2 " align="right">
             10
        </td>
        <td data-r="" class="cell3 " align="right">
             300
        </td>
     </tr>  
     <tr class="row-2">
        <td>2</td>
        <td>     Total Unemployment</td>
        <td></td>
        <td data-r="" class="cell1 " align="right">
              1000
        </td>
        <td data-r="" class="cell2 " align="right">
               1010 
        </td>
        <td data-r="" class="cell3 " align="right">
                400
        </td>
        <td data-r="" class="cell4 " align="right">
                 24
        </td>
        <td data-r="" class="cell5 " align="right">
                 58
        </td>
     </tr>
```

Below is the code

```
    //capture the rows in a list
    IList<IWebElement> rows = 
    //caputure the first row data _driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='data_3']/div/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr    [@class]"));

     IList<IWebElement> row1 = _driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='data_3']/div/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr   [@class][3]/td[@class]"));

      for (int row = 4; row <= rows.Count; row++)
    IList<IWebElement> columns = _driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@id='data_3']/div/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[@class][" + row + "]/td[@class]")); 

            for (int j = 0; j < columns.Count; j++)
                 {
    //I am trying to verify that the first row is g
                  Assert.IsTrue(int.Parse(columns[j].Text) <= int.Parse(row1[j].Text));

         }


  }
```

the Assertion seems to compare every data with the first row data. I want to modify it in a way that the formula compares on a row by row basis.

Comment: Please format your code. Some of it is formatted. Some of it is not. Can you also edit your question and tell us what error you are getting, if any? We will also need to see all or a representative snippet of the HTML you are dealing with.

Comment: And make sure you share the right html of the table, I see the column numbers not matching in the row 2 when compare to row 1. And even there are blank cells in between.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, your issue is coming from how you grab "columns":

```
IList<IWebElement> columns = _driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@id='data_3']/div/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[@class][" + row + "]/td[@class]"));
```

I can't verify if your XPath is actually grabbing what you think it is, for example:

```
IList<IWebElement> row1 = _driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='data_3']/div/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr   [@class][3]/td[@class]"));
```

I'll continue with the assumption that your XPath is doing exactly what is intended, just make sure you check you're indexing the right number of rows and such. You can make your code a little more legible with some string formatting and simple functions:

```
string xpathTableBase = "//*[@id='data_3']/div/div/div[3]/table/tbody";

// grab all rows
List<IWebElement> tableRows = _driver.FindElements(By.XPath(
    $"{xpathTableBase}tr[contains(@class, 'row']"));

// grab the "first" row cells in a list
List<IWebElement> firstRowCells = _driver.FindElements(By.XPath(
   $"{xpathTableBase}/tr[@class][3]/td[@class]"));
```

It might do you good to read up on some of the documentation: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/

Note that you can use FindElements on an object that implements the `IWebElement` interface. If you grab each of the table rows (`<tr>`) as an `IWebElement`, this gives you access to the child elements without creating confusing loops.

And just one side comment, your loop `for (int row = 4; row <= rows.Count; row++)` makes an assumption that the elements are returned in order of how they appear in the DOM. In my practice with Selenium this is usually the case but just understand this is not guaranteed by the interface.

> the Assertion seems to compare every data with the first row data. I want to modify it in a way that the formula compares on a row by row basis.

This is confusing. Your for loop iterates through each row, then iterates through each cell in that row. It then compares the cell value in column `j` with the cell value in column `j` of the first row -- this is exactly the desired behavior you are describing.

Cleaning up your loop might help understand what's happening:

```
// loop through each row in the table, after our "first" row
for (int row = 4; row < tableRows.Count; row++)
{
    // grab the cells of the current row
    List<IWebElement> cells = tableRows[row].FindElements(By.XPath("//td[@class]"));

    // zip the lists to make iterating a little easier
    // and prevents indexing issues if the rows don't match in column length
    var zippedList = firstRowCells.Zip(cells, (x, y) => (x, y));
    foreach((firstCell, cell) in zippedList)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(int.Parse(cell.Text) <= int.Parse(firstCell.Text));
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

If you're saying you want to compare the SUM of the first row against all subsequent rows, then you need to do that in the loop:

```
// loop through each row in the table, after our "first" row
for (int row = 4; row < tableRows.Count; row++)
{
    // grab the cells of the current row
    List<IWebElement> cells = tableRows[row].FindElements(By.XPath("//td[@class]"));

    int firstRowSum = firstRowCells.Select(x => int.Parse(x.Text)).Sum();
    int currentRowSum = cells.Select(x => int.Parse(x.Text)).Sum();

    Assert.IsTrue(currentRowSum <= firstRowSum);
}
```

*(edited some typos in the code)*